# Error when running mongo image - docker-entrypoint.sh: line 381

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu

After installing Ubuntu v20 and then installing docker:

```
$ docker network create test-network

$ docker pull mongo

$ docker run --network test-network --name mongodb \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
    -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pawwrord \
    mongo
```

I got an error like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 381:    25 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "${mongodHackedArgs[@]}" --fork
```

Do you know what the problem is? I just need some guidance to investigate the problem.

**UPDATE**

I don't have any problem with other docker hub images.

Specifically only when I want to run mongo, I got this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MongoDB 5.0 requires a Sandy Bridge or newer CPU. Get a newer processor or use an older version of MongoDB.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-54407

Comment: Is it ok that I cant see `docker-entrypoint.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: I changed my `mongo:latest` image with `mongo:4.4` image and I got the same error again.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri If you are getting the same error with v4.4 then the issue is not the sandybridge requirement which is new in v5.0 and doesn't affect v4.4.

Comment: Same problem here. I run Docker on a VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 20.04. The CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210M CPU @ 2.60GHz`, which should be more recent than Sandy Bridge. However, I am successful with *mongo:4.4*.

Comment: @berndbausch - What is your host OS?

Comment: My Docker host is Ubuntu 20. The host of the Ubuntu VM is Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using the WSL2 or the hyper-v backend? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/. If the latter, it appears that hyper-v may disable access to the AVX instructions: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390.

Comment: On a RaspberryPi, mongo:5.0.2 does not work. mongo:4.4.8 works.

Comment: @d-sm Can you cite a source?

Comment: This is the correct answer. For docker images with modern MongoDB (6.0+), see my unofficial repo: https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-docker/.

Answer (score 11):

I have exactly same problem with yours, i try to run on my local computer work but not in VM.

[thanks to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68394912/11884143) I simply changed mongo's version to 4.4 from latest which is 5.0 and running well. Maybe need newer CPU

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! a simple link to probable solution can be provided in the question comment instead of as answer.

Comment: Thanks for advice @AtulDwivedi, i can't do that before i get 50 reputation

Answer (score 5):

It's a shortcoming in the available instructions of your CPU.  Mongo 5.0 requires CPU instructions only available in Sandy Bridge era or more recent.

I had this problem using a Proxmox VM, which defaults to a simpler virtual CPU.  Simply changing the virtual CPU to type "host" fixed the problem, by allowing the VM CPU to include all the instructions of the host CPU.

If you are running directly on metal, you'll need a newer CPU.  Good luck!

Comment: any idea on how to change this on oracle virtula box?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=84423) might help.

Comment: Wow! Who would have thought. Thank you, just my case. You helped me.