# Ubuntu 18.04 - mongodb 5.0 install - (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to install MongoDB Community Edition 5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 using these official [instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). However, when I get to `sudo systemctl start mongod` step to start the service, it gives me following error doing `sudo systemctl status mongod`

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Fri 2021-07-30 18:50:50 CDT; 5min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 125616 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 125616 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Jul 30 18:50:50 mongodocker.cigi.illinois.edu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jul 30 18:50:50 mongodocker.cigi.illinois.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Jul 30 18:50:50 mongodocker.cigi.illinois.edu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I've tried uninstalling mongodb `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-*`, deleting the directories `/var/lib/mongodb` & `/var/log/mongodb` and installing from scratch.

NOTE: I'm going with default configurations specified in `/etc/mongod.conf`

`dmesg` shows following

```
traps: mongod[125616] trap invalid opcode ip:56330c9ed3da sp:7ffece242670 error:0 in mongod[563308adc000+5021000]
```

Comment: `sudo -u mongodb /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` printed following `Illegal instruction`

Comment: Ah, nevermind, apparently CENTOS uses the user mongod, but ubuntu uses the user mongodb.  How convenient.

Comment: About the only other thing I could suggest is a review of the log files at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.

Comment: The directory `/var/log/mongodb/` is empty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392064/error-when-running-mongo-image-docker-entrypoint-sh-line-381/68394912#68394912

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading Ubuntu first. We're up to 22.04 now. Why so far behind?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SURJIT KUMAR, but, we can need  purge with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org
```

and,

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
```

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

p/s: follow by: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

It's working with me, many thanks.