# Illegal instruction (core dumped) mongodb Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, lts

I installed mongodb-org 5.0.2 as per official documentation

Codes i used to install via Terminal given below:

```
     1.wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -

     2.echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-5.0.list

     3.sudo apt-get update

     4.sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After installation i started using

```
     sudo systemctl start mongod
```

if I use `mongod --version` command it shows :-

```
     Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392064/error-when-running-mongo-image-docker-entrypoint-sh-line-381/68394912#68394912

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when running mongo image - docker-entrypoint.sh: line 381](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392064/error-when-running-mongo-image-docker-entrypoint-sh-line-381)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Stop the `mongod` process by issuing the following command:-

   ```
   sudo service mongod stop
   ```
2. Remove any MongoDB packages that you had previously installed:-

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
   ```
3. Remove MongoDB databases and log files:-

   ```
   sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
   ```
4. Then reinstall MongoDB 4.4.x
5. Import the public key used by the package management system:-

   ```
   wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
6. The following instruction is for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):-

   ```
   echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
   ```
7. Update Apt

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
8. Install MongoDB 4.4.x (Now available 4.4.15)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.4.15 mongodb-org-server=4.4.15 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.15 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.15 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.15
   ```
9. Use `mongod --version` to check if it is successfully installed
10. If you encounter any error while using `mongod`

    ```
    sudo mkdir /data
    cd /data
    sudo mkdir db
    sudo pkill -f mongod
    ```
11. Then use sudo `mongod` command.
12. After long research, it is now working totally fine thanks to this community and Internet.

**EDIT:**

After following above steps:

if below error occurs:

```
mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

then remove below files and start `mongod` service again.

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo service mongod start
```

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309575/mangodb-service-failed-with-result-exit-code)

Comment: My endless problems with Mongo core dump version 5 was solved by going back to version 4.4.8 as per your instructions. Thank you.

Comment: E: Version '4.4.8' for 'mongodb-org' was not found

Comment: @VityaSchel - v4.4.8 is an old version and no longer available. There are newer v4.4.x releases though. So long as you don't have a v5 repo configured (in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/) then you could just exclude the '=4.4.8' from each packagename when installing. If you want to see what versions are available, try 'apt policy mongodb-org'.

Comment: I had to do `rm /etc/apt/sources.list/mongo*`  to remove old files of previous installations.

Comment: Important note - don't forget to mark installed packages as upgrade-protected so that next apt upgrade won't upgrade your version of mongodb to the latest version and return all problems. sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>(sudo apt-mark showhold to list holded packages)

Comment: @JeremyDavis It now only shows 5.0+ releases which all doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: v4.4.x is still available, but only for older distros. I.e. if you use Debian 10/Buster or Ubuntu 20.04 you should be good. So either downgrade your OS or upgrade your hardware (or compile MongoDB from source).

Comment: So sad, that you have to downgrade the whole os to get it working!

Answer (score 7):

Not the best variant, to downgrade your mongo installation.

Problem cause your host or vm doesnt support an AVX instruction of cpu.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-community-5-0-12-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-ubuntu-20-04-5-lts/204332

Check if your host supports AVX instruction (lscpu | grep avx), if does, seems you running mongo in vm, check your hypervisor configured to passthrough host cpu features into VM.

If host doesnt support AVX instructions, so downgrade is your choise

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came across this same problem with MongoDB v5 and Ubuntu 22.04. Downgrading to v4.4.25 solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you. We recently migrated our MeshCentral VM to Proxmox, and the default Proxmox CPU does not enable AVX. Mongodb just crashes with "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" instead of showing a useful error. The solution for us was to change the CPU model to "host" in Proxmox which provides the guest with AVX.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you use proxmox or other hypervisor, please check your processors setting. Set processors type to host may resolve this issue.