# Mongo DB deployment not working in kubernetes because processor doesn't have AVX support

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to deploy a `mongo db` deployment together with service, as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo:5.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef: 
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Even though everything seems to be configured right and deployed, it gets to a `CrashLoopBackOff` state instead of `Running`, using a `kubectl logs <deployment-name>` I get the following error:

```
MongoDB 5.0+ requires a CPU with AVX support, and your current system does not appear to have that!
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal instruction (core dumped) mongodb Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937131/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-mongodb-ubuntu-20-04-lts) Full working solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To solve this issue I had to run an older `mongo-db` docker image version (4.4.6), as follows:

```
image: mongo:4.4.6
```

Reference:

[Mongo 5.0.0 crashes but 4.4.6 works #485](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/485)

Comment: I don't know why this is an accepted answer, but we people can't just downgrade their database! Even just for local development.

Answer (score 9):

The latest version that can work WITHOUT `AVX` is

```yaml
image: mongo:4.4.18
```

but if you are using it on a VPS, its worth a shot to contact their support, mine said that they changed the CPU type and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Windows+VirtualBox this will resolve the issue:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

perhaps host reboot required.

Answer (score 2):

Mongo DB deployment not working in kubernetes because processor doesn't have AVX support

Use mongo:4.4.7 instead of mongo:latest to resolve the above AVX support issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your CPU does not support AVX, then indeed you're out of luck, however most CPUs sold in the last decade (and almost all consumer CPUs) have AVX support.

If your mongodb deployment fails in a VM , especially a VM hosted on a proxmox host, then proxmox by default does not allow VMs to be aware the Host CPU supports AVX.

In the VM's hardware settings, set the CPU type to "host" for it to mirror the hypervisor's CPU capabilities, then reboot the VM.

Comment: Using proxmox 8.1 here, by default the VMs are created using processor type  `x86-64-v2-AES` which will run into the AVX error. Assuming, your processor really supports AVX, you can switch the VM processor type to `host` or `x86-64-v3`, then I was able to deploy Mongo 6